# Consulta Right Join Sql

Tags: join, sql

**Buen día**

Mi consulta del problema es el siguiente y no entiendo el por que me pasa.

Intento hacer un `LEFT OUTER JOIN` pero con la condición que tengo simplemente no me deja.

```
SELECT cve_ent_des, ROUND(SUM(ImporteDet/1000000), 2) AS Importe
FROM Activa 
where seleccion in ('Entregado','Entr')
GROUP BY cve_ent_des
ORDER BY cve_ent_des
```

**Esta consulta me lo siguiente:**

```
cve_ent_des         Importe
Estado de México    14.43
Sonora              14.08
```

Sin embargo lo que yo quiero es que me dé todos los estados, aunque estos tengan 0 en `Importe`.

Al hacer la consulta con el catálogo correspondiente, me sigue dando los mismos datos, tanto si lo hago con LEFT OUTER JOIN, como si lo hiciera con RIGHT OUTER JOIN, es decir la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT cve_ent_des, ROUND(SUM(ImporteDet/1000000), 2) AS Importe
FROM Activa a
RIGHT OUTER JOIN cat_ent_Buena as e
ON a.cve_ent =e.ident 
where seleccion in ('Entregado','Entr')
GROUP BY cve_ent_des
ORDER BY cve_ent_des
```

Al hacer el `select * from Cat_ent_Buena` lo que arroja son las 32 entidades, para terminar quisiera que la salida me mostrara de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero de alguna forma simplemente y al intentar hacer la consulta no me respeta el LEft JOIN y me sigue mostrando los mismos dos registros de las entidades.

De antemano muchas gracias si pudieran resolver mi duda.

**Saludos!**

Comment: ¿Que motor de base de datos usas? ¿podrías agregar los nombres de columnas de las dos tablas?

Comment: Es SQL Server y las dos tablas son:
Activa (Que es mi información con importes)
cat_ent_Buena(Que es el catalogo de entidades a la que quiero darle el Join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es mostrar todas las entidades, tengan o no Importe, por lo cual puedes plantear esto:

```
SELECT e.cve_ent_des, 
       ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(ImporteDet/1000000), 2),0) AS Importe
       FROM cat_ent_Buena as e
       LEFT JOIN Activa as a
            ON a.cve_ent = e.ident 
            AND seleccion in ('Entregado', 'Entr')
       GROUP BY e.cve_ent_des
       ORDER BY e.cve_ent_des
```

**Impotante**

- la idea es que `cve_ent_des` es el nombre de la entidad en la tabla `cat_ent_Buena`, no sé si es así efectivamente por que no lo puede deducir de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal de tu consulta radica en que aplicas un filtro con la clausula `where`, que excluye los registros de las entidades que no tienen información.

Esto es porque, en realidad, la condición no pertenece al filtro de la información, sino al *join* de las tablas.

En términos prácticos, debes cambiarla de lugar:

```
SELECT e.cve_ent_des, ROUND(SUM(ImporteDet/1000000), 2) AS Importe
  FROM Activa a
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN cat_ent_Buena as e
                     ON a.cve_ent =e.ident 
                    and a.seleccion in ('Entregado','Entr')
GROUP BY e.cve_ent_des
ORDER BY e.cve_ent_des
```

He prefijado la columna `cve_ent_des` para que la tome de la tabla  `cat_ent_Buena`, pues diría que un *buen* motor de base de datos debiera rechazar ejecutar la consulta como estaba, con esa columna ambigua, es decir, si existe en ambas tablas, no se especifica de donde traerla.

Y si no existe en ambas tablas, esa sería otra parte del problema, hay que traer el nombre de la entidad de la tabla `cve_ent_des` y no de `Activa`.

Esta consulta dejará el valor `NULL` en la columna importe para todas las entidades para las que no haya registros relacionados en la tabla `Activa`. Si quieres ver un cero, generalmente hay funciones para colocar un cero donde hay un `null`. La estándar y que debiera estar soportada en todos los motores es

## `coalesce()`

Esta función toma N parámetros y devuelve como resultado el primero que no sea `null`.

```
select coalesce(null, null, 1) from MiTabla
```

Devolverá el valor 1

En tu caso concreto, encierra el valor del resultado de `SUM(...)`, que devolverá nulo para las filas de marras, en esta función, algo así:

```
select e.cve_ent_des, ROUND(coalesce(SUM(ImporteDet/1000000), 0), 2) as Importe
```

Si tu motor no soporta `coalesce()` (cosa que dudo), intenta utilizar `isNull()` (un invento de SQL server que siguieron otros).  `isNull` tiene la misma idea que `coalesce()` pero acepta solo dos parámetros.

Si no existe ninguno de estos, refiere a la documentación de tu motor para encontrar alguna función similar a estas para realizar la tarea.